# How to upgrade Visual studio 2008 project in Visual Studio 2012/2015 ?(How to Open Project)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, web-config

How to upgrade Visual studio 2008 project in Visual Studio 2012/2015 ?
How to Open Projects in VS 2012/2015.

when I open existing project folder it showing like :
   [image]

There is no **.sln** file.

can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a website there won't be a solution 
You have open it with File>Open Website option.
Check if it's a website or web application project.